# Convert an Octal number to Decimal and Hexadecimal

Tags: delphi

I am writing a program that converts an Octal number to Decimal and Hexadecimal. I wrote a function called `OctToInt`.

```
function OctToInt(Value: string): Longint;
var
  i: Integer;
  int: Integer;
begin
  int := 0;
  for i := 0 to Length(Value) do
  begin
    int := int * 8 + StrToInt(Copy(Value, i, 1));
  end;
  Result := int;
end;
```

I call this function in this way:

```
var oct:integer;
begin
 oct:=OctToInt(Edit13.Text);
 Edit15.Text:=IntToStr(oct);
end;
```

When I type `34` (Octal) the decimal number should be 28 but the program gives me 220. Do you know why?

Also, do you have any idea about a converter OctToHex?

Comment: [`Are you sure you wrote it`](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/math/convert_an_octal_number_to_integer.html) :-) ?

Comment: I've already saw that too :D

Comment: It could happen, after all giving your variables sensible names isn't widely held belief system. Var int : integer. My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: I gave you an answer to both of these questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16782872/62576) months ago. The same solution that worked for Lazarus works for Delphi. (The code I posted there converts from an integer to any number radix from 2 (binary) to 36, and there's a function that reverses that (from binary or octal back to integer.)

Comment: Any time you call `Copy` and the third parameter is the literal 1, it's a *code smell*. Prefer to use the string's array notation: `Value[i]`. Had you written your code the idiomatic way, it would have failed at run time with an out-of-bounds error, alerting you to the real problem in your code. You also could have figured out the problem if you'd used the debugger: You might have noticed that the loop ran too many times, for example. However, a key to effective debugging is understanding how the code is supposed to work in the first place, which rarely happens when you copy others' code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change the start of "your" `for` with 1.

```
function OctToInt(Value: string): Longint;
var
  i: Integer;
  int: Integer;
begin
  int := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(Value) do  //here you need 1, not 0
  begin
    int := int * 8 + StrToInt(Copy(Value, i, 1));
  end;
  Result := int;
end;
```

The conversion Octal-Hexadecimal could be hard to do, so I suggest you another way:

```
EditHexadecimal.Text:=(IntToHex(StrToInt(EditInteger.Text),8));
```

As you can see here, with this code the `EditHexadecimal` is the Edit where you put the hexadecimal number. With that line I convert a number from decimal to hexadecimal.

You already have the decimal number because you get it with the function `OctToInt`, so you don't need more code.

Comment: are you sure that "IntToHex(StrToInt(EditInteger.Text),8)" works?

Comment: If I posted you this as answer, it means that I've tested it and it works :/

Answer (score 7):

This code accepts a string with a base-8 representation of an integer, and returns the corresponding integer:

```
function IntPower(const N, k: integer): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := 1;
  for i := 1 to k do
    result := result * N;
end;

function OctToInt(const Value: string): integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(Value) do
    inc(result, StrToInt(Value[i]) * IntPower(8, Length(Value) - i));
end;
```

When it comes to converting an integer to a hexadecimal string representation, you already have `IntToHex`.

Comment: I suppose this was downvoted because the first character has a Unicode codepoint divisible by 4.

Answer (score 0):

i made this formula so you can process octals in batches of 3-digits at a time - it's been tested from 000 through 777 to perfectly generate the decimal integer from octals :

> if your octals are in a variable `oct`  and temp placeholder `o2`

then

> `(37 < oct % 100)*8 + int(0.08*(oct-(o2=oct%10))+0.7017)*8 + o2`

if you wanna further streamline that without the placeholder, then its

> `(37 < oct%100)*8 + int(0.7017+0.08*(oct-(oct%=10)))*8 + oct`

- the "0.7017" is ***possibly*** `sin(-10*π/8)` or `1/sqrt(2)`, or just `2^(1/-2)`, but since i found the formula via regression i'm not 100% sure on this.

Another fast trick is that if all 3 digits are the same number - 222 333 555 etc, simply take the first digit then multiply by 73 (cuz 73 in octal is 111). The sequence chain of multipliers for 2-6 consecutive matching digits are

> 9, 73, 585, 4681, 37449

(it also happens that within this list, for each x,
one of `{x-2,x+0,x+2}` is prime